# Appending NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, ios, arrays

I am attempting to fill up `NSMutableArray`s with an unknown sized list of strings.

I have declared the arrays and am reading in from a `plist` successfully into my `tempWordStr`, but when I try to append the array from the `tempWordStr`, the array object remains `null`.  I tried a couple of variants (below) but the `_wordLengthArray` remains empty with `0` objects either way even though the `tempWordStr` has the string. This seems pretty basic but have been struggling for a couple of hours.

```
[_wordLengthArray addObject:tempWordStr];
[self.wordLengthArray addObject:tempWordStr];
```

Comment: Are you sure that _wordLengthArray is not nil?

Comment: Did you initialize the array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before you can call a method, such as `addObject:` on an object, such as `NSMutableArray` you need to initialize it. So before all of your code, do `_wordLengthArray = [NSMutableArray array];`

Speaking more generally, if you call a method on an object that hasn't been initialized (aka it's nil) it simply returns nil/null. That's why you don't get any errors, it just silently fails.

Comment: Thank You.  Just a matter of alloc, my oversight - over thinking.